# Resize partitions used in Debian software RAID 1 mirror

Tags: linux, debian, raid, partition

I have a simple RAID1 setup with a few drives.

I've realised that one of the partitions is not aligned to a cylendar boundary and I'm concerned that this is a bad thing that will cause me grief at some point.

Normally I would use gparted to tweak the boundaries, but how to do this when the partitions are used in a RAID1 array?

I don't want to go down LVM route because I don't understand it and the simple way works fine, so I'd like to avoid that learning curve.

Comment: You're in systems administration and you are trying to avoid the (very simple) learning curve of LVM? I fear you're going to have a hard time.

Comment: @EEAA LOL! KISS YAGNI etc. But perhaps I should. Thing is, I'm not in systems admin as the full extent of my job - small charity, big job etc. But if you say it's easy perhaps it's worth it.

Answer (score 3):

If you temporarily can live with only a single disk (no redundancy), it's probably the easiest route to simply let the misaligned partition fail, remove it from the array and also remove any RAID-metadata from it (replace md-devices and partitions as required).

For repartitioning, all partitions from this disk need to be offline - this is likely to be the place, if you only do use a single partition for your RAID1 setup and don't share any other partitions with RAID or anything else (e.g. swap space). If you're only using a single partition on that disk and use that partition only for RAID1, you may start this way:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --fail /dev/sdb1 --remove /dev/sdb1
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sdb1
```

If you do have any additional partitions on the same physical drive, do "fail, remove, zero" them as well.

Please do doublecheck you're using the correct partition from the correct disk. If you've selected the wrong partition and already "failed" your partition or even zeroed the superblock, do run `mdadm  /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1` right away to re-build your RAID1 and re-start the re-partitioning after successful reconstruction.

After zeroing the superblock, you should re-partition the disk according to your needs (using gparted, parted, sfdisk, cfdisk, fdisk, ...). Of course, the resized partition needs to be (at least) the very same size from the first RAID disk.

After partitioning, do issue a

```
blockdev --rereadpt /dev/sdb
```

to ensure your kernel is using the latest partition table and do add the "failed" partition to your MD device:

```
mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdb1
```

Do the same step for all the other partions and MD devices as well.

The drive will instantly go into recovery mode and copy data from your other disk to the "new" disk. You can monitor the recovery progress using `cat /proc/mdstat`.

Regarding LVM: LVM essentially is "just another layer" between disk and your filesystem, think of it replacing statically-sized partitions by something which can be changed online. Filesystems can be grown (and sometimes shrinked) online as well, and along with LVM, this gives you some flexibility. Logical volumes can also be added, removed or changed on the fly, and you can add more disks so you can extend existing logical volumes as well.

For example, you don't need to think of the exact partitioning scheme, as you may later add some more space to an existing filesystem online. If your system is using a single partition for all of its files (probably additional to a small /boot-partition) and you don't need to add more space, you won't see that much benefit by LVM.

LVM also won't help that much if the physical volume used for LVM already is using a misaligned partition. Technically, one may add a dataoffset when preparing a physical volume (PV) for using it in LVM, but that's usually not that much of a difference. Fixing a misaligned LVM essentially involves the same headaches a misaligned RAID does, but requires additional, different tools for doing so.

If a LVM PV does reside on a correctly aligned partition, new created logical volumes just happen to be correctly aligned as well, but that's just a mere coincidence due to the fact of large-sized physical extents. If a LVM setup is configured to use 1KB-sized physical extents on a 4k-shaped disk, misaliged logical volumes simply might be the standard.

Yet still, LVM is "the way to go" for more flexibility and I do recommend taking a look at the basic concepts of LVM.

Comment: Thanks for a very full answer. I do have lots of partitions on the disks (each is part of a RAID1 array), not just one. "misaliged logical volumes simply would be the standard" -- maybe I should just not worry about the warning anyway? Perhaps it doesn't make much difference?

Comment: Misaligned partitions may result in a major IO performance issue, e.g. giving you only half of the expected performance.

Comment: You still may use the same concept for re-partitioning the whole disk: let all of the partitions "fail", remove all of them, re-partition your disk and add the partitions to the MD devices again. I updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: "Of course, the resized partition needs to be (at least) the very same size from the first RAID disk." how can this be the case - if I increase sdb1 to align to the boundary then sdb2 will have been shrunk a bit :-/

Comment: Essentially, do resize the partions on your one disk to be of the very same size than the partitions on the other disk. If sda is your "correctly" aligned disk and sdb the misaligned disk, resizing sdb1 to be of the same size than sda1 will shrink sdb2 a little bit. However, sda2 is likely to be smaller than the current sdb2 is. Or, if you do have more than two partitions, take a look at sizes of all partitions: one of them is likely to be larger. Make them all the same size (of the ones from the "correct" disk), and you're set.

Comment: Thanks. They're all aligned wrong! They're all identically aligned wrong. I need to change them all! I think I've found answer, though, just experimenting on a test box first!